# What is @StaticMetamodel and SingularAttribute<Obj,Obj>?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection

I am trying to figure out this code for about two hours now, for example in below class what are these fields representing?

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.ListAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;
import java.util.UUID;

@StaticMetamodel(Address.class)
public class Address_ extends  {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Address, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Address, UUID> personId;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Address, Person> person;
}
```

The `Address.class` is a java class which has the following definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address", schema = "public")
public class Address{
    private Long id;
    private Person person;
    private UUID personId;
    //....
}
```

Can you, please, explain what are the `@StaticMetamodel` and `@SingularAttribute` annotations used for? It might be simple but I can't understand.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/metamodel.html#metamodel-static):

> A static metamodel is a series of classes that "mirror" the entities
>   and embeddables in the domain model and provide static access to the
>   metadata about the mirrored class's attributes.

The static metamodel has the following properties:

- For each managed class `X` in package `p`, a metamodel class `X_` in package `p` is created.
- For every persistent non-collection-valued attribute `y` declared by class `X`, where the type of `y` is `Y`, the metamodel class must contain a declaration as follows:

`SingularAttribute` example:

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<X, Y> y;
```

The static metamodel is useful for creating **type-safe queries** with the JPA's Criteria API.

For example, let's have the following two entities, `Order` and `Item`:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne 
    Customer customer;

    @OneToMany 
    Set<Item> items;

    BigDecimal totalCost;

    // accessors
}
```

and the `Item` entity:

```
@Entity  
public class Item { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    int quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    Order order;

    // accessors
}
```

Here's a typesafe criteria query, build with the Criteria API:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> cq = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
SetJoin<Order, Item> itemNode = cq.from(Order.class).join(Order_.items);
cq.where(cb.equal(itemNode.get(Item_.id), 5)).distinct(true);
```

Note the usage of `Item_.id` and `Order_.item`. Those access *statically* the static meta-model properties (which mirror the entity properties) and this way it's *ensured* that the query is build properly.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i cant understand this part 'provide static access to the metadata' i mean what do we gain here? why one should not use the entity itself? what can i achive using metamodel that i cant get it other way oround?

Comment: is it about concurrency ?

Comment: No, it means you're not supposed to instantiate an entity object in order to get metadata for a field.

Comment: @dave - ^^ In other words, the static metamodel makes it so you don't **need** to instantiate an entity object to obtain metadata about its fields. This is a good thing.

Comment: @kocko Can I put this autogenerated entity_.class in another package than the orginial entity ?

Comment: So, what I understood, if we know a field name is used for setting example matcher or some where where you need to mention field name as "fname". So, in that case, you will point to Employee_.fname.getName(). Here we are using metadata field name. So, incase you change field you can't know until you use and you need to debug, but this staticmodel can handle this

Comment: check this one https://thoughts-on-java.org/static-metamodel/

Comment: .withMatcher("lastName", match -> match.ignoreCase().startsWith()) can show error if entity value get changed, but .withMatcher(Author_.lastName.getName(), match -> match.ignoreCase().startsWith()) can handle. I read somewhere

Answer (score 6):

I've been thinking about this a lot lately as I've been trying to learn and understand JPA. I believe I have an answer to your question: Why do we need MetaModels, and why can't we just use the Entity Model?

Take a look at this entity:

```
@Entity  
public class Item { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    int quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    Order order;

    // accessors
}
```

Note that none of the properties on the Entity have the keyword static. That means that in order to use them, we need to create a new Object.

When we are building queries with CriteriaBuilder, we don't need to create an object... we just want to use the properties on the Entity to generate our query. This is the reason we have MetaModels! They create static properties that we can access without having to create an object. So we can can do things like Konstantin mentioned:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Order> cq = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
SetJoin<Order, Item> itemNode = cq.from(Order.class).join(Order_.items);
cq.where(cb.equal(itemNode.get(Item_.id), 5)).distinct(true);
```

Here, we aren't making an "Item" object... we just need to know the properties of it. The static properties on the MetaModel enable us to do so!